# How to obtain an element from RealmList using the position in onBindViewHolder()?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a RecyclerView where I get data like so:

```
Cat obj = getData().get(position);
holder.setText(obj.getSomeCat())
```

But in the case of RealmList objects, how do I retrieve them?

```
holder.setText(obj.getAnotherCat().get(position).getCat());
```

give me

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: rowIndex > available rows: 1
>   > 1

Comment: Well the RealmList has nothing to do with the RealmResults that's inside the RecyclerView, so the position has nothing to do with the RealmList of the cat inside the RealmResults. You'd have to check the cat's list of the other cat. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah, I know that's where I've messed up. I just don't know how to get it right. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to get the cat name for that specific position. I have a RealmList where I store multiple features of a 'cat'. How do I retrieve all the features of the cat from within the RealmList for a certain position of obj?

Comment: What do you want to do with said features? Are you trying to show them all in new rows, or in the same row?